# Maintain user session for multple domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a project where multiple domains are running for single project means all domain have same A record mapped and we have hosted project  on IIS. And it's working fine, but I want to use same session if use switch from www.abc.com to www.xyz.com ( we have 1000  different domains) he doesn't need to login again as its part of same project.

I am already tired but does not get any proper solution

Please suggest the best way. Please don't suggest post message. We are using  ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: Consider `JWT` also look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788792/asp-net-sessions-over-multiple-domains

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new web service which should work as an authentication service. Imagine it something like google does with firebase. You can use your new service to handle logins and share the session among your other domains.